# Ionic 3, use single custom theme for both iOS and Android

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

my ionic app renders different looking widgets for iOS and Android platform.

What is the best way to keep custom looking button, input boxes etc for both flavors? How do I theme for all platforms once?

Answer (score 2):

You can set your entire app in iOS, Android, or Windows mode by adding this in `app.module.ts` :

```
imports: [
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{
    mode: 'md'
  })
]
```

This will set your app in Android style. You can use following modes : `md`, `ios`, `wp`